# List every sub folder in reverse

Tags: powershell

I have a UNC path

```
$path = "\\ad.testxyz.com\corp\technology\software\data\iso"
```

I need to apply permissions to the following paths:

```
\\ad.testxyz.com\corp\technology\software\data
\\ad.testxyz.com\corp\technology\software
\\ad.testxyz.com\corp\technology
```

And I don't want to do anything to \\ad.testxyz.com\corp\technology, or higher.

Here is my code so far. This "works", but I've run into a snag with directories that have spaces in them.

```cs
$path = "\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology\test\information\software"
#$path = "\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology\payer information\extracts\item load"

# Split string by "\", remove empty elements
$root = (($path.Split("\")).Split('',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries))

# Recursively list all top level folders in [path]. (Excludes DFS root)
for ($i=2; $i -lt $root.Length - 1; $i++) {
    # Recursively build every directory up the tree
    $leaf = "\" + $root[$i]
    $branch += $leaf
    $trunk = "\\" + $root[0] + "\" + $root[1] + $branch

    # do work
    Write-Host $trunk
}
```

Outputs:

```
\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology
\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology\test
\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology\test\information
```

But if I try and use a path with spaces in it, I get the following

```
\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology
\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology\payer
\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology\payer\information
\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology\payer\information\extracts
\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology\payer\information\extracts\item
```

Comment: don't do this _manually_! [*grin*] either use `Split-Path` OR use the `.Parent` property of a dirinfo object that you get back from `Get-ChildItem`. i would likely use the 2nd of those.

Comment: To make your code work, replace the split with this `$path.Split("\",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)`, as the second split separates the path parts that contain spaces. Also, what @Lee_Dailey said!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. This works for anyone else.

```
$path = "\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology\test\payer information\software"

# Split string by "\", remove null elements
$tree = $path.Split([system.io.path]::DirectorySeparatorChar) | ? {$_}

# Recursively list all top level folders in [path]. (Excludes DFS root)
For ($i=2; $i -lt $tree.Length - 1; $i++) {
    # Recursively build every directory up the tree
    $leaf = "\" + $tree[$i]
    $branch += $leaf
    $trunk = "\\" + $tree[0] + "\" + $tree[1] + $branch

    # do work
    Write-Host $trunk
}
```

Outputs:

\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology
\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology\test
\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology\test\payer information

Answer (score 0):

there are builtin ways to handle path manipulation. [*grin*]

the simplest would be to use the `.Parent` property of the `DirInfo` object you get back from `Get-ChildItem` or from `Get-Item` when run against a filesystem. that likely cannot be used since it seems you only have strings to work with.

the next easiest is to use `Split-Path` and the `-Parent` switch to jump up one level at a time. that is what the below code does.

```
$SamplePathList = @(
    '\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology\test\information\software'
    '\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology\payer information\extracts\item load'
    )
$StopAt = '\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology'

$Results = foreach ($SPL_Item in $SamplePathList)
    {
    $TempPath = $SPL_Item
    # send starting path to $Results
    $TempPath

    while ($TempPath -ne $StopAt)
        {
        $TempPath = Split-Path -Path $TempPath -Parent
        # send to $Results
        $TempPath
        }
    }

$Results
```

output ...

```
\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology\test\information\software
\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology\test\information
\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology\test
\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology
\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology\payer information\extracts\item load
\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology\payer information\extracts
\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology\payer information
\\ad.domain.com\corp\technology
```